# Hotel Reservation and Room Availability

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[image: Hotel Reservation System ER Diagram]

I am using CodeIgniter Framework. I want to get all the available rooms on a particular date. The algorithm is as follows:

1) I shall give a date to check the availability of the room.

2) The System shall look into the table **"hotelbrancheshasreservations"** and shall select the **reservation** ids based on branch id and `status = 'active'`.

3) Then all the active **reservations** are selected and are joined with **reservation** table.

4) Only those **reservations** are extracted from "**reservation**" table after join which are not reserved on provided date and are active. There would be thousands of reservations in this table but that should be skipped.

5) Then the active reservations are joined with "**reservedrooms**" table and this will provide the rooms nos. which are although currently reserved but can be reserved for some other dates which have no conflict with current reservation date.

6) Finally, currently reserved rooms are also joined with "**hotelrooms**" table and all the available rooms returned for new reservation.

7) So a room can be reserved multiple times but with different dates.

I was not be able to develop a proper query in CodeIgniter to get all the available rooms if I provide some date like `$startdate = 2016-05-16` and `$enddate = 2016-05-27`.

The **datatype** in **MySQL** Db is date.

---

```
function joinReserv($branchid, $startdate, $enddate, $db)
{
$status = "active";
$this->$db->trans_start();
$this->$db->select('reservationid, startdate, enddate, hotelbrancheshasreservations.status');
$this->$db->from('reservation');
$this->$db->join('hotelbrancheshasreservations', 'hotelbrancheshasreservations.reservations_reservationsid = reservation.reservationid');
$this->$db->where('(hotelbrancheshasreservations.status = '."'".$status."')");
$this->$db->where('(hotelbrancheshasreservations.hotelbranches_hotelbranchesid ='."'".$branchid."')");
$this->$db->where('(startdate BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "' . $enddate . '") OR (enddate BETWEEN "' . $startdate . '" AND "' . $enddate . '")');
$this->$db->where('( "'. $startdate . '" BETWEEN startdate AND enddate  ) OR ( "'. $enddate . '" BETWEEN startdate AND enddate)');
$result = $this->$db->get()->result_array();
$this->$db->trans_complete();       
return $result;
}
```

If I provide `startdate 2016-05-24` and `enddate 2016-05-26`, then it selects a reservation which is as follows:

```
[{"reservationid":"KHAN2016Q224","startdate":"2016-05-23","enddate":"2016-05-27","status":"pending"}]
```

This reservation should be skipped as it is not active in table "**hotelbrancheshasreservations**"

It selects those reservations which are within the provided dates but are not active. I want to select those reservations which are active and available on provided dates.